# deploying production mode with Vue-cli created project

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vue.js

Bit of a n00b question:
I created project with vue-cli using webpack.
On my windows machine I run "npm un dev" and I get a frontend server with HMR and so on.
Now I want to deploy my app to a production machine - ubuntu on DigitalOcean.

What are the steps I must take? I'm not very familiar with the logic of how it's supposed to work. If my ubuntu machine has NODE_ENV set to production, it won't install any of the devDependancies and i'm not able to build anything. So I guess I'll have to change that? If yes then it doesn't make any sense since it's a production machine.

And do I have to create another node/express server to serve index.html? Won't it supposed to work out-of-the-box somehow?

Thanks :)

Comment: Well, you can build things for production locally and then deploy that to the server.Vue-cli has command `npm run build` which bundle everything and place it under the dist folder.

Comment: So i will create another seperate node/express server and just statically serve index.html (which in turn imports dist folder for js)?

Comment: Yeah, you will need some file that would start node server into the dist folder.Recently I deployed app to heroku server in pretty same way https://postimg.org/image/ubc68hcjb/

Comment: You can tell npm to install dev dependencies as well even if your NODE_ENV is set to production. However, the logic behind the dependencies is that if you're building for production you should only need the production dependencies, the dev dependencies are there for the devs e.g. when compiling static libraries or for tools used when developing, like the server package you use while developing.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR Build on your local machine and everything you need will be outputted in the `./dist/` directory, just copy the contents over to the webroot on your production server and you're good to go.

The webpack template handles most of the stuff for you.

Step you need to take to release:

1. Run `npm run build` on your local machine
2. Copy the contents of the generated `./dist/` directory to your server webroot
3. That's it!

When you run `npm run build`, the pre-configured build script sets the node environment to production, and builds with only the stuff that should be in production, it also optimizes the code and removes debug capabilities. When it comes to dependencies webpack takes care of that and includes them in the generated javascript files located in the `./dist/js/`, so you need not concern yourself with copying over the `node_modules/` directory either.
It also copies over everything in your `static` directory and `src/assets` directory to the `./dist/` directory to be prepare for a release. And resolves all the references to the new path generated by webpack.

The production server should not be concerned with building the vue app, run the build command on your local machine to keep dev dependencies away from your production server. I recommend against installing webpack and other dev tools on your production server. It just pollutes the server with things not needed there.
Some development tools could potentially produce alot of issues on production servers. So best practice is to never install them.

You could optionally create your own release script that uses ftp or rsync, whatver you prefer to copy everything in the `./dist/` directory to the production server webroot. This could be a script in bash, if on windows, run it in git bash or something similar for example.

Hope that cleared things up, congrats on your first vue release!